# Disable shadows while Weight painting

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Hello dear Blender community!

How do I remove those shadows while painting in Weight Painting Mode?... I can't see what I'm painting... I tried to change the lamp mode to "Hemi" but this only works in Object mode...  I put a picture bellow.
[image: List item]

Comment: Try to ask about only one problem for one question. This allows visitors with the same problem to have greater chances to find the answer and those willing to give an answer to be specific on that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first problem, try pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to wireframe or solid mode. You are in material mode, which does do the shadows. See [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html) for all of the modes.

Comment: Yep, works! Thank you! I hope i'll get an answer for my other question too.

Comment: Solid shading also works without the wireframe overlay.

Comment: @sambler Cool! How do you do that?

Comment: @JF - Solid Shading? it's one of the [viewport shading options](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html)